# document.onmousedown is an event then why?

Tags: javascript, events

I have javascript code to disable right click.

here it is:

```
 document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(event){
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }


}
```

although this code is working as expected but i have a problem about `document.onmousedown`,what i know about it that it is an event accessed through DOM then  it is assigned a value and the strange thing to me is that later this value is declared as function, how??

Comment: i think you should check how to register events https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: This is called 'hoisting' if i understand your question

Comment: _“I have javascript code to disable right click”_ – sorry, after reading that I can’t be bothered to read any further. (It’s _idiotic_, sorry – f.e. it also disables me using my mouse gestures in my browser, or using right click to open a link in a new tab, etc. – so if you want to make your page unusable, you’re on your own with that kind of stupid plan.)

Comment: @CBroe yes i know it is unworthy to disable right click but as i am learning javascript so i just experimented with it to see how it is feasible.In practice i am not gonna apply it at all.thnx for response..

Comment: @ArunKillu thnxx that link is very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is event handler that is called when event happens.

Comment: And that function is passed event object automatically, we can accept it's reference in any variable.. thnxx your led me to the right place.